# Spooky Mysterious Unknown Weights

Tags: armature, weight-painting

[image: This is Frank.]
I'm still pretty new to blender but I've been working on this guy for a while. He's only being used as a ragdoll, so I haven't included any fancy IK bones or constraints or whatever. Looking at the picture above, you can probably see some problems already, but I'm really only worried about this one right now:
[image: Note that I moved the clavicle out of place a bit.]

So in weight paint mode, I did all my weight painty stuff, saved it, and tested it for any weird contortions in pose mode. And I noticed this. It wasn't an issue while painting it, so I reverted to the last save but, because I saved at the wrong time, the problem was still there. (Just noticed I spelled clavicle wrong in the photo, but youknowhwatimean)

His right arm and leg bones were moving the mesh in odd ways, pulling his face and left leg when I hadn't assigned them to. I ended up subtracting all the paint I had put on to find some sorta reason to why the mesh was moving. So everything's completely blue when you select any of the bones, but now all of the mesh, with the exception of his left arm, is connected to the armature.
[image: ...]

If anyone could identify the problem, that would obviously be great. I'm not sure if this is a big problem or a small problem, my best guess is that I messed up when duplicating the left arm and leg (the ones I made first) over to the right side. Maybe I pressed a wrong button, skipped a step, or made a mistake when parenting the mesh to to armature (with automatic weights). So yeah, if anybody has an solution, or just an idea, that would be great.

Comment: nvm I got it. I just had to play around with that "clean" button over on the left.